# PHP: Unable to store data

Tags: php, sql, forms

I've form in my `php` page . Using `form` I want to store the information filled by user using `form`. But it doesn't store the information in my `database`. 
Here is the my `form`.

```
<form id="fadd-form" name="AddForm" action="index.php" method="post" onsubmit="return(validateAll());">
                <div id="form-content">
                 <fieldset>
                    <div class="fieldgroup">
                     <label for="FriendName">Friend Name</label>
                     <input type="text" name="frnd" id="txtFname" onBlur="validate(this,document.getElementById('FName'))" >                                                            <span id="FName" class="help"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="fieldgroup">
                     <label for="ImageName">Select Image</label>
                     <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
                     <tr>
                       <td><img src="img/face0.png" width="45" height="45"><input type="radio" value="0" name="fimg" checked> </td>
                       <td><img src="img/face1.png" width="45" height="45"><input type="radio" value="1" name="fimg"> </td>
                       <td><img src="img/face2.png" width="45" height="45"><input type="radio" value="2" name="fimg"> </td>  
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                       <td><img src="img/face3.png" width="45" height="45"><input type="radio" value="3" name="fimg"> </td>
                       <td><img src="img/face4.png" width="45" height="45"><input type="radio" value="4" name="fimg"> </td>
                       <td><img src="img/face5.png" width="45" height="45"><input type="radio" value="5" name="fimg"> </td>  
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                       <td><img src="img/face6.png" width="45" height="45"><input type="radio" value="6" name="fimg"> </td>
                       <td><img src="img/face7.png" width="45" height="45"><input type="radio" value="7" name="fimg"> </td>

                     </tr>
                     </table>
                     <span id="fcheck" class="help"></span>
                    </div>
                     <div class="fieldgroup" style="text-align:center"><br>                      
                        <input type="submit" name="sub" value="SUBMIT">  
                    </div>
               </fieldset>
              </div> 
             </form>
```

this is my php code .

```
   <?php 
        if(isset($_REQUEST['sub']))
        {
            $img=$_POST["fimg"];
            $fname=$_POST["frnd"];

            $UserName = $_SESSION['username'];

            $frId = new FriendName();
            $newId = $frId->returnId("friendList");

            include_once './config.php';    

            $now = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata'));
            $currentDate = $now->format('Y-m-d');
            $currentTime = $now->format('H:i:s');

            $con=mysqli_connect(mysql_host,mysql_user,mysql_password,mysql_database);   
            $order = "INSERT INTO friendlist (UserName,FriendName,FriendId,IdGivenBy,EventDate,EventTime,FRIEND_IMAGE_NO) VALUES ('$UserName', '$fname','$newId','Web','$currentDate','$currentTime','$img')";
                mysqli_query($con,$order);


        }
    } 
    else 
    {

    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Use prepared statements. Your objects (FriendName, DateTime) will get converted according to it's `__toString()` representation.

Comment: Use [mysqli_error](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) after mysqli_query - this will help you to determine an exact problem.

Comment: if I remove the action defined above in the form, than the php present on this [age executes and the from gets submitted and data gets stored
But once I put that action .. the php is never called and it moves tp next page without storing the data

Comment: Do you have your mysqli_connect() parameters defined?

Comment: @AmitKumar: What do you mean, if you remove the action?  Is this form not posting to the page which has this PHP code?  Because that... would *clearly* cause the code not to execute.

Comment: f I remove the action defined above in the form, than the php present on this [age executes and the from gets submitted and data gets stored But once I put that action .. the php is never called and it moves tp next page without storing the data

Comment: in what page do you have your php code?

Comment: it is in the same page !!

Comment: then just put action="#"

Comment: Than how i do navigate or redirect to some other page after submitting the form

Comment: just use `header("location:index.php")` after  `mysqli_query($con,$order)`

Comment: you can redirect it at the final of the php code using header("Location:index.php");

Comment: I did that But it says
Cannot modify header information, header already sent by.....

Comment: just use `ob_start()`in top of your page.

Comment: should i write it  inside <?php  ?> or somewhere else .

Comment: yes inside of <?php ?> tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you change your form action to `#`.
use `header("location:index.php")` after `mysqli_query($con,$order)` to redirect the page.

and use `ob_start()` to avoid `header already sent` error.

in the end of page write this : `ob_flush();`

Answer (score -3):

I think the program is run into the else becouse the $_Request variable don't contain the $_POST['sub'] variable. If you change if(isset($_POST['sub'])), it will work.